# Combination of two word into a double word in TwinCAT 3?

Tags: modbus

I am using TwinCAT 3.

I am trying to read the floating variable via MODBUS TCP.
The read variables are in a word array. How can I convert 2 word into float/real? I mean both word first want to combine and then save as another variable as DWORD.
Moreover when I have to do swapping?

Comment: What have you tried? Providing more info (e.g. what programming language are you using, sample code, what registers are you retrieving and what values do you get back vs expected result etc). You might find [this converter](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) useful (put in raw response data and it will decode in a range of ways).

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array of 2 WORDs and swap the memory directly with REAL type using MEMCPY as they are both 4 bytes.
Example:

---

PROGRAM MAIN 
VAR

RealValue: REAL; 
words: ARRAY [0..1] OF WORD; 
firstWord: WORD; //read from modbus 
secondWord: WORD; //read from modbus

END_VAR

words[0] := firstWord;
words[1] := secondWord;

MEMCPY(ADR(RealValue), ADR(words), 4);

---

MEMCPY takes 3 inputs respectively; destination address, source address, and number of bytes to be transfered.